# kubectl is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli, amazon-eks, kubectl

after installing the whole k8s on EC2 instance I've stuck with permissions problem as:

```
kubectl get ns

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::00000000:user/NotRootAccount is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::000000000:user/NotRootAccount:role/DeveleapEksRole
E0807 13:35:32.960611    2137 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://55F0139D24BC8EE6FF9E008F6A817620.gr7.eu-north-1.eks.amazonaws.com/api?timeout=32s": getting credentials: exec: executable aws failed with exit code 254
```

--------------------------------------**fake arn for security reasons.**--------------------------------------

I will list all my policies and trust relationships aswell:

**Permissions:**

```
AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy            AWS      managed    Directly
AmazonEKSClusterPolicy          AWS      managed    Directly
AmazonEKSServicePolicy          AWS      managed    Directly
AmazonEKSVPCResourceController  AWS      managed    Directly
AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy       AWS      managed    Directly
AWSQuickSightListIAM            AWS      managed    Directly
IAMFullAccess                   AWS      managed    Directly
IAMSelfManageServiceSpecificCredentials     AWS      managed    Directly
```

**Roles Trust Relationship:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::0009:user/NotRootAccount"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

**policy :**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::0600009:role/DeveleapEksRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

at the end I want to access eks and make myself argocd but something is denying the connection..

Comment: `arn:aws:iam::000000000:user/NotRootAccount:role/DeveleapEksRole` looks weird, why is there a user AND a role in that arn?

Comment: fake arn for security reasons like i said above

Comment: why is there a user AND a role in that arn? If you (incorrectly) fake / omit all the data points you prevent us from figuring out what is wrong.

Comment: i've seen somewhere that you need to put in aws eks update-kubeconfig like that, I will try to remove the user section or role section and update

Comment: If you are use EKS, do you have aws-iam-authenticator configured with the IAM principal you want to use to access your cluster? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html

Comment: ```kubectl get roles -A
E0807 15:11:38.487641    2197 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials```
and my config is on the right account

Comment: @luk2302 i've removed everything and did just regoin and cluster name but now im stuck at ```error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)```

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue these days and [this guide](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/eks-kubernetes-object-access-error) might be useful.

Long story short, the user which created the cluster MUST add every other user in `aws-auth` config map, IAM permissions aren't enough.

Keep an eye on EKS logs, other permissions might be needed as well, for example in order to proper configure [fluent bit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Container-Insights-setup-logs-FluentBit.html) i had to add *CloudWatchFullAccess* policy into *AWSServiceRole-EKSNodeGroup* role.

Comment: i've looked at it and:
```aws sts get-caller-identity --query Arn
"arn:aws:iam::0000000:user/NotRootAccount"```
and then when i try the next step it's the same error as before..
```kubectl edit configmap aws-auth -n kube-system
E0807 15:17:47.339667    2388 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials```

Comment: @zolo the next step must be made by the cluster owner, i got that error whenever i tried to do that with my user, although i got myself permissions from AWS IAM they are no use if cluster owner doesn't perform that part himself. you can test it by using your current user to create a cluster and then add yourself other users to it.

Comment: i tried to make new cluster, policy,role and users... nothing seems to work